# How many threads, at least, are needed to launch an iOS application?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, concurrency, background-process

I know that iOS support multithreading. I want to know which threads at least are needed to launch an iOS application.

Comment: I have been writing iOS applications all my life (almost :-) and never needed to know this. What would you do with the answer?

Answer (score 5):

There will be at least the UI Thread and your "Application Thread".

Many api calls create threads too

If you want to see how many threads are currently active, check the cpu tab in the debug navigator of XCode while your app is running, you will see a list of the threads:

[image]